# Equation numbering lost

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm using equation numbering in a book at section level. Somehow, after chapter 10, equation numbers turn 0 and remain that. I'm not doing anything special before that. Any clue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) We're going to see a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages to be able to diagnose the problem :)

Comment: In composing the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) , start with `\documentclass{<class>}`, add the appropriate packages and preamble, and you can just make the first 10 chapters empty, and then add a formula to chapter 11 and show that the numbering is _lost_.  If this does not reproduce the problem, add to it until it does.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the problem in the form of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) , it is going to be difficult to determine the source of the problem or suggest a fix.  Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: With no MWE this is too localized. Request reopening if one is available.